# Evaluating a regular expression range

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a nice way to evaluate a regular expression range, say, for a url such as

```
http://example.com/[a-z]/[0-9].htm
```

This would be converted into:

```
http://example.com/a/0.htm
http://example.com/a/1.htm
http://example.com/a/2.htm
...
http://example.com/a/9.htm
...
http://example.com/z/0.htm
http://example.com/z/1.htm
http://example.com/z/2.htm
...
http://example.com/z/9.htm
```

I've been scratching my head about this, and there's no pretty way of doing it without going through the alphabet and looping through numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do this, it's not that hard to generate the strings using recursion. Here's a snippet to do just that in Java:

```
public class Explode {
    static void dfs(String prefix, String suffix) {
        final int k = suffix.indexOf('[');
        if (k == -1) {
            System.out.println(prefix + suffix);
        } else {
            prefix += suffix.substring(0, k);
            char from = suffix.charAt(k+1);
            char to = suffix.charAt(k+3);
            suffix = suffix.substring(k+5);
            for (char ch = from; ch <= to; ch++) {
                dfs(prefix + ch, suffix);               
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String template = "http://example.com/[a-c]/[0-2][x-z].htm";
        dfs("", template);
    }
}
```

([see full output](http://ideone.com/vSNKW))

This is a standard recursive tuple generator, but with some string infixing in between. It's trivial to port to C#. You'd want to use a mutable `StringBuilder`-like class for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no way to expand regular expressions in general. Your example

```
http://foo.com/[a-z]/[0-9].htm
```

is a very easy regex without `*` or `+` for instance. How would you expand such a regex?

In your case you might get away with some loops, but as I said - this is a *untypical* (easy) regex.

Comment: No, I would say that the regex ranges I'm looking to create are reasonably simple alphanumeric ones but, yes, I agree that other ranges would be *quite* hard to do.

Comment: What for do you need it? Some kind of tests?

Comment: I suppose that simple url ranges would probably be my primary use. There is no real *need* for it. If anything, it's more of a thought experiment. :)

Comment: Just an idea: You could **brute-force** the regex. For every `[]` you find you assume a character set (like a-z, A-z, 0-9, and a few special chars) and use all combinations as an input. However the performance would be poor and the miss rate could be high (if you forget any valid characters).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking. I've started by regexing the er... regex and then parse it, determining if it's a string or int range. That's about as simple as I can get it right now. :)

Comment: @Dan, If you tried to use the approach of "regexing the regex" with more complex regexes, you might see that you cannot do it fully: The language of regular expressions is not regular itself, e.g. because it has nested groups (think about expressions like `(a(bc)?)+`). But simple regexes of the form `([^][]*\\[[^]]-[^]]\\])*` you could split by regexes and handle with loops and recursion.